# How can I change the visibility of several events at once in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

How can I change the visibility of several events at once in Google Calendar?

[image]

Comment: This might be more of a workaround than a solution, but here goes: create a calendar for this type of event, and choose a better default visibility for that calendar.